# Would running multiple console processes on Heroku slow the others down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, heroku, console, paperclip

I'm on a Cedar stack with Heroku and am regenerating 10 thumbnails for about 30,000 different photos.

I'm starting up separate console processes so each one can process 1000 photos, that way I don't run in to timeout issues (I was having trouble with that before) and I can concurrently generate new thumbnails (which would theoretically make the whole process go much faster).

I've got about 12 console processes going right now, and each one is running Paperclip's thumbnail regeneration.

It seems like as I add more processes, the others are starting to slow down. Is that true or am I just imagining things? And is there any way to make sure they keep running at full speed?

Here's the output from `heroku ps`:

```
Process  State       Command                            
-------  ----------  ---------------------------------  
run.14   up for 35m  bundle exec rails console          
run.16   up for 31m  bundle exec rails console          
run.18   up for 28m  bundle exec rails console          
run.19   up for 27m  bundle exec rails console          
run.20   up for 21m  bundle exec rails console          
run.21   up for 20m  bundle exec rails console          
run.22   up for 18m  bundle exec rails console          
run.23   up for 8m   bundle exec rails console          
run.24   up for 8m   bundle exec rails console          
run.25   up for 6m   bundle exec rails console          
run.26   up for 5m   bundle exec rails console          
web.1    up for 3h   bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate processes are separate, so nothing on the Heroku side will slow down regardless of whether you have one process, or one hundred.

However, all of your processes will be looking at the same data, so this could be a bottleneck.  With this approach your also running the risk of resizing the same images several times over as you're not necessarily checking the same files are being picked up by more than one process properly.

Ideally you want to run some sort of queue with workers working that queue, however, the time to create this might not be practical for a one off event such as this.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a rake task.

It's a good solution for this kind of process.

In /lib/tasks
create a file my_task.rake

namespace :image_update do

```
desc '....'
  task :update => :environment do
    User.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 100) do |user_batch|
      for user in user_batch
        user. ...
      end
    end    
  end
end
```

and launch it in the console with

```
rake image_update:update
```

Comment: I'm doing separate processes partly so that I can concurrently generate new thumbnails...meaning if I had 12 processes going I could generate 12 at a time instead of one at a time. So that's why I'm not doing a single rake task or find_in_batches.

Comment: You can also create with this rake task a delayed Job for each object. If you use heroku for exemple you change the number of worker to the maximum during the time you have jobs. It will be fast ;)